# Access a constant defined in class from a mixin included in the class

Tags: ruby

I have a mixin (`Api::Utility`) that is referenced by two classes: `Api::Utility::One::WorkstationClient` and `Api::Utility::Two::WorkstationClient`.  Both classes define a constant, `BASE_URL`, that I'd like to access in the mixin.  When I attempt to access the constant, I get an error that reads `NameError (uninitialized constant Epic::Api::Utility::BASE_URL).

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

module Api

  class WorkstationClientFactory

    def self.create_client(version = :v2)
      case version
      when :v2
        Two::WorkstationClient.new()
      when :v1
        One::WorkstationClient.new()
      else
        raise ArgumentError, "'#{version.inspect}' is not a valid version symbol.  Valid: [:v1|:v2]."
      end
    end

  end # /WorkstationClientFactory

  # Api::Utility
  module Utility
    def bar
      puts "BASE_URL: #{BASE_URL}"
    end
  end

  module One
    # Api::One::WorkstationClient
    class WorkstationClient
      include Api::Utility

      BASE_URL = 'https://domain.tld/api/v1'

      def initialize()
        puts "Creating #{self.class.name}"
      end

    end # /WorkstationClient
  end # One

  module Two
    # Api::Two::WorkstationClient
    class WorkstationClient
      include Api::Utility

      BASE_URL = 'https://domain.tld/api/v2'

      def initialize()
        puts "Creating #{self.class.name}"
      end

    end # /WorkstationClient
  end # /Two

end # /module

v1 = Api::WorkstationClientFactory.create_client(:v1)
v1.bar <-- error here
BASE_URL: https://domain.tld/api/v1  <-- desired result

v2 = Api::WorkstationClientFactory.create_client(:v2)
v2.bar <-- error here
BASE_URL: https://domain.tld/api/v2  <-- desired result
```

What's the right way to access the `BASE_URL` in the mixin, in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `self.class::BASE_URL`.